# Save position of the dragged widget

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

Using jquery ui's draggable widget to move an image up/down to show the desired part of the image inside the container (when image is too large to fit inside container). The Image can be dragged up/down to display the ideal part inside the container (initially the center region of image is visible inside the container). The position value is then saved for future reloads.

When image is dragged a yellow button appears at the bottom showing the current position set by function `dragCover()`. This is the value that is stored for future. For testing, when you click on that button, it updates the position of the image by setting the css top prop. If value is correct, image should not move because the value would be equal to the current position, since `dragCover` is setting an incorrect value, image moves away from its current position. Try dragging the image all the way down and then clicking on yellow box, it moves back up.

https://codepen.io/apprence/pen/KKVwKBN

Comment: I found various Syntax errors in your CSS.

Comment: It's scss preprocessor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a little unclear what you're going for in the end, in your `click` callback. I created the following pseudo view port type of example to see if this is the type of function / result you're looking to get.

```js
$(function() {
  function calcPerc(el, vp) {
    el = $(el), vp = $(vp);
    var y1 = el.position().top;
    var h = el.height();
    return parseFloat(((y1 / h) * 100).toFixed(2));
  }

  function showData(t, p) {
    $(".top").html(t);
    $(".perc").html(p);
  }

  $(".item").draggable({
    scroll: false,
    axis: "y",
    cursor: "move",
    containment: [0, -899, 0, 1],
    drag: function(e, ui) {
      showData(ui.position.top, calcPerc(this, $(".viewport")));
    }
  });

  $(".perc").click(function() {
    var offsetVal = parseFloat($(this).text()) * 10;
    console.log(offsetVal);
    $(".item").css({
      top: offsetVal + "%"
    });
  });

  $(".buttons button").click(function() {
    $(".item").css("top", $(this).html());
    showData($(".item").position().top, calcPerc($(".item"), $(".viewport")));
  });
});
```

```css
.viewport {
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px dashed #222;
  top: 0;
}

.small {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
}

.tall {
  width: 201px;
  height: 1000px;
}

.item {
  background-color: #ccf;
  position: absolute;
  top: -299px;
}

.item span {
  padding-bottom: 80px;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #222;
}

.show {
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  border-radius: 3px;
  width: 3em;
  padding: 3px;
}

.show.buttons {
  width: 100px;
}

.top {
  top: 20px;
  left: 220px;
}

.perc {
  top: 50px;
  left: 220px;
}

.buttons {
  top: 80px;
  left: 220px;
}

.buttons button {
  width: 100%;
}

.ghost {
  width: 201px;
  background-color: #fff;
  opacity: 0.75;
  height: 900px;
  position: absolute;
}

.after {
  top: 101px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div class="container">

  <div class="small viewport">
    <div class="tall item">
      <span>0</span>
      <span>1</span>
      <span>2</span>
      <span>3</span>
      <span>4</span>
      <span>5</span>
      <span>6</span>
      <span>7</span>
      <span>8</span>
      <span>9</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="ghost after"></div>
  <div class="show top">-299</div>
  <div class="show perc">-29.9</div>
  <div class="show buttons">
    <button>0%</button>
    <button>-25%</button>
    <button>-500%</button>
    <button>-75%</button>
    <button>-900%</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/top

> When `position` is set to `absolute` or `fixed`, the `top` property specifies the distance between the element's top edge and the top edge of its containing block.
>
> A `<percentage>` of the containing block's height.

So, for my example, the containing block is 100px tall. Therefore, a `top` set to `-25%`, we have to calculate that:

```
top = 100 * -.25
top = -25
```

Therefore, we need to increase this exponentially. To get the proper location, `-29.12%`, needs to be `-291.2%`.

```
top = 100 * -2.912
top = -291.2
```

This should help you with your image movement and view port. Personally, I would store and reload the exact pixel value, but if you desire to store the percentage, you can do so.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that. I'm trying to implement a cover like the one you see in social media sites like facebook where users upload an image on their profile, image can be  repositioned by moving it up/down and saving the position, have a look at the one in fb.

Comment: @JamieWhite I am familiar with it and would **strongly** advise using length values over percentages.

Comment: @JamieWhite yes, both 25% and 75% were just to clarify / show you an example.

Comment: Dragging with mouse scroll wheel or swiping up/down in laptop touchpad possible? @Twisty

Comment: @JamieWhite Possible? Yes, it's possible, you just have to adjust the position of the element with different events. I would advise creating a function that can move it in a specific direction and then use that function with the various callbacks for `mousewheel` or `scroll` type of events.

Comment: I was hoping draggable widget would have this option.

Comment: @JamieWhite all it's features and options are discussed here: https://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/